# Rails variable can not be saved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have such strange problem:
I have this method:

```
def create_default_workspace(user)
  @workspace = Workspace.new(title: "#{user.name}'s workspace")
  @workspace.save
  user.selected_workspace_id = @workspace.id
  if user.save
    puts "Saved"
  else
    puts "not saved"
  end
end
```

Which gives me "not saved". Do you have any ideas why variable `user` can not be saved?

Comment: did you know about strong parameter in rails?

Comment: Replace your `.save` method with `.save!` and add error's full stacktrace here please.

Comment: @uzaif you are completely right! I forgot this point... I have added params.require(:user).permit(:selected_workspace_id) and now is ok.

Comment: can i post as answer?

Comment: sure, please post it

Comment: please accept answer if it useful for you @Neon_10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This Code

```
def create_default_workspace(user)
  @workspace = Workspace.new(workspace_params)
  @workspace.save
  user.selected_workspace_id = @workspace.id
  if user.save
    puts "Saved"
  else
    puts "not saved"
  end
end

private 

  def workspace_params
    params.require(:workspace).permit(:title)
  end
```

You Forgot to add strong params method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot about strong parameters, as @uzaif mentioned. After adding params.require(:user).permit(:selected_workspace_id) works well